# What would happen in a hypothetical universe without the other forces other than gravity?

Tags: forces, gravity, weak-interaction, strong-force

What would be the rules of a hypothetical universe where there is only gravitational force, and weak strong and EM force do not exist? What would be the consequences of that?

Comment: Presumably there just wouldn't be a universe as we know it.